# given polynomial has a root in $Z_p$...

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

To check $f_x$ is irrudicble or not in $f_p$ check wheather 0,1,2 , p-1 is a root of $f_x$...if any of this is a root then it is not irrudicible..

is this method applicable here?

Comment: @  Dietrich Burde...then what is method to solve this type of problems....

Comment: @DietrichBurde I also thought that's what the OP wrote (and most probably that's what he actually meant), yet read carefully what he wrote: "...if any of these [elements of $\;\Bbb F_p\;$] is a root then $\;f\;$ is **not** irreducible"...which is true.

Comment: Right, I should rather say that the converse need not be true:  if a polynomial has no roots, then it need not be irreducible.

Answer (score 0):

The polynomial $f(x)$ has a double root $x=-1$ over $\mathbb{F}_3$, so it is not difficult to find its factorization by division, namely
$$
f(x)=(x^2+1)(x+1)^2
$$
Over $\mathbb{F}_7$, it has a root $x=1$, and we see that $f(x)=(x^3+5)(x-1)$, and $x^3+5$ has no root over $\mathbb{F}_7$, and hence is irreducible. Hence $(c)$ is correct. As for $(d)$, over the integers, the polynomial is irreducible. It has no root, and the equation $f(x)=(x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)$ gives a contradiction.

Comment: @ Dietrich Burde...please explain d...

Comment: $f(x)$ is not a product of *any* two quadratic factors, hence $(d)$ cannot hold.